# Groot Installation on ROS2 Foxy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I tried to install groot on linux. When I install it, I faced this problems. Anyone know how to install it using ROS way?

```
[ 76%] Linking CXX executable Groot
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Groot.dir/bt_editor/main.cpp.o: in function `BT::TreeNode::~TreeNode()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2BT8TreeNodeD2Ev[_ZN2BT8TreeNodeD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for BT::TreeNode'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393920/groot-installation-on-ros2-foxy/) by [enyuin](https://answers.ros.org/users/74920/enyuin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2022-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello [@osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/), I believe what you are referring to is integration of Groot with the Nav2 stack.

You can however install groot on foxy following the documentation [here](https://github.com/BehaviorTree/Groot#compilation-instructions-ros). Just use colcon build --packages-select groot instead of catkin_make

You can then run it with:

```
./<your-workspace-path>/build/groot/Groot
```

---

Originally posted by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) with karma: 166 on 2022-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-10**:
You are right @tnajjar. Thank you!

**Comment by [enyuin](https://answers.ros.org/users/74920/enyuin/) on 2022-01-10**:
TThanks. It works!

**Comment by [K88](https://answers.ros.org/users/120644/k88/) on 2022-10-14**:
Once compiled and sourced, Groot can also be run with $ros2 run groot Groot.